# Missing assets only in iOS release build after eject the application

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I ejected my application from expo 38 and since then my static/local images are not showing when I run the app in release mode on iOS but no errors are reported. It works perfectly on Android for both release and debug mode.
I am using images with png extension, all images are locally added on my project path like (assets/images).
I tried to create an IPA file from my Xcode11.7 then I installed IPA on my real device. In my application not showing local images while running the app on a real device.
How to solve this issue? Please help me

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue like the following code

When ejecting, the expo is supposed to generate a metro.config.js file that looks like that

```
module.exports = {
    transformer: {
        assetPlugins: ['expo-asset/tools/hashAssetFiles']
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck with that issue for the long time as well. I'm not sure if this is the case in your case (cool combination of words :D), but I'll tell you how did I resolve it:
It might be caused by expo-updates, you have to run expo publish (with the correct buildNumber in your app.config.js file) every time you're going to deploy a new build, so the newest javascript bundle gets supplied to your build as it's going to start. To fetch that updated javascript bundle you have to add something like this to your app startup phase:

```
import * as Updates from "expo-updates";

 const fetchUpdates = async () => {
 try {
  const update = await Updates.checkForUpdateAsync();

  if (update.isAvailable) {
    await Updates.fetchUpdateAsync()
    // NOTIFY USER HERE
    Updates.reloadAsync()
  }
   } catch (e) {
  // HANDLE ERROR HERE
}}
```

and call `await fetchUpdates();` somewhere where your app loads resources (if you do some preloading like - caching fonts and etc. this would be the perfect place).
You can also use `await SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();` then call `await fetchUpdates();` and then `SplashScreen.hideAsync();` if you're using expo-splashscreen.
Here I'll leave some useful links which could also help :

1. https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/9386
2. https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/updates/
3. https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/splash-screen/

Hope this was helpful ;)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please check the string of imageName(is it correct?)
Please use SwiftGen to avoid any risk of typo when using a String.
[SwiftGen](https://github.com/SwiftGen/SwiftGen)